# Continuity of $\text{Im}\frac{z}{z-1},\frac{\text{Re }z}{z},\text{Re }z^2,\frac{z\text{Re }z}{\left|z\right|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

Find the set of points for which the given functions are continuous on that points.

- $\text{Im}\frac{z}{z-1}$
- $\frac{\text{Re }z}{z}$
- $\text{Re }z^2$
- $\frac{z\text{Re }z}{\left|z\right|}$

---

My definition of continuity is:Assume $S \subseteq \mathbb C$ and $f:S \to \mathbb C$ is a complex function and $z_0 \in S$, $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ if

1. $f$ is defined at a neighborhood of $z_0$ contained in $S$
2. $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)$

For the first one we have that $$\text{Im}\frac{z}{z-1}=\text{Im}\frac{x\left(x-1\right)+y^{2}-iy}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{-y}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}}$$

First of all for every $z_0 \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(1,0)\}$ there is a neighborhood of $z_0$ containing in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(1,0)\}$ such that $f$ is defined on that neighborhood, then for such arbitrary $z_0=x_0+iy_0$:$$\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{-y}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{-y_0}{\left(x_0-1\right)^{2}+y_0^{2}}=f(z_0)$$

So the set of all points for which  $\text{Im}\frac{z}{z-1}$ is continuous on that interval is its domain $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(1,0)\}$.

---

For the second one $\frac{\text{Re }z}{z}=\frac{x}{x+iy}$, with a similar argument like the first one we see that for every $z_0 \in \mathbb C \setminus \{(0,0)\}$:$$\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}\frac{x}{x+iy}=\frac{x_0}{x+iy_0}=f(z_0)$$
So the set of all points for which $\text{Re }z^2$ is continuous on that interval is its domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

---

For the third one for every $z_0 \in \mathbb C$;
$$\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)}x^2+y^2=x_0^2+y^2_0=f(z_0)$$
So the set of all points for which  $\frac{\text{Re }z}{z}$ is continuous on that interval is its domain $\mathbb C$

---

I used a similar argument to the other ones and it looks that $\frac{z\text{Re }z}{\left|z\right|}$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, It looks that the set of all points for which a complex rational function is continuous on that interval is its domain and that's why in all 4 cases the same happened.
Continuity

---

I want to know whether my answers are correct or not, so if you have an alternative answer first check mine and approve/disapprove the validity and then provide yours.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those four functions is continuous at every point at which it is defined. That's so because each of them can be obtained from other continuous functions through composition and arithmetic operations. For instance, the maps $z\mapsto z$ and $z\mapsto1$ are continuous. Therefore, $z\mapsto z-1$ is continuous and so $z\mapsto z-1$ is continuous. Also, the imaginary part function is continuous. So, the first function ($z\mapsto\operatorname{Im}\frac z{z-1}$) is continuous.

Comment: Are my arguments about continuity of these 4 functions valid?

Comment: Yes, they are.${}$